# babel config setup for testing

Tags: react-native, babeljs, ts-jest, react-native-testing-library

I have setup testing in my react native app with typescript using React-native-testing-library. I have configured my `babel,config.js` as below. There is an odd issue though.

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
    '@babel/preset-react',
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
  ],
  sourceMaps: true,
  plugins: [
    [
      'module:react-native-dotenv',
      {
        moduleName: '@env',
        path: '.env',
        blacklist: null,
        whitelist: null,
        safe: false,
        allowUndefined: true,
      },
    ],
    // ['@babel/plugin-transform-private-methods', {loose: true}],
  ],
};
```

When I uncomment `['@babel/plugin-transform-private-methods', {loose: true}],`  The tests do not work and the `FlatList` does but when I do comment it out the `FlatList` gives me the below error and the tests do not work?

`ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of undefined`

My `FLatList` works fine on my main branch where I have not added the testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running into the same issue. I was able to run my tests and use a FlatList in my code without issues thanks to this thread and comment:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29084#issuecomment-1463493342

I updated my `babel.config.js` to this (stripped of some irrelevant plugins):

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    'babel-preset-expo',
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
    'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
  ],
  plugins: [
    ['@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types', { loose: true }],
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }],
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods', { loose: true }],
  ],
};
```